# Seeking Clarity on the Intuition Behind Weak Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I am currently facing difficulties in grasping the concept of weak convergence. My struggle lies not with the technical aspects, but rather with understanding the essence and rationale behind its definition, which appears somewhat unintuitive to me.

**Definition (Weak Convergence):** Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and a sequence $\{\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots\}$ of distributions on $\mathbb{R}$ (which each $\mu_n = L(X_n)$ for some r.v$X_n$), we say that this sequence converges in distribution to a distribution $\mu$ if, for any bounded continuous function $f$, the integral $\int f d\mu_n$ converges to $\int f d\mu$ as $n \to \infty$.

This definition puzzles me. It seems more natural to expect that convergence would be defined in terms of the convergence of integrals for indicators of any Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$. Although I am aware that such a definition might introduce certain difficulties, it intuitively feels more straightforward to me.

I am unable to discern the underlying idea and intuition behind adopting the given definition for weak convergence. Could you please illuminate the reasoning and intuition that underpin this particular formulation of weak convergence?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of weak convergence is to have a notion of convergence of measures that can "see" the topology of $\mathbb{R}$, and that's why continuous functions appear in the definition.  If you allow all Borel indicators, then you are only using the Borel structure of $\mathbb{R}$, and that makes it indistinguishable from any other uncountable standard Borel space ($\mathbb{R}^2$, $[0,1]$, any manifold, separable Banach spaces, Cantor set, Hilbert cube, Baire space, etc...).

If you allow all Borel indicators, you have the topology of setwise convergence.  It's a legitimate object of study (see for instance Bogachev's *Measure Theory*) but is not nearly as useful.

As you note in your comment, using Borel indicators, we find that if $x_n \to x$, we cannot conclude that $\delta_{x_n} \to \delta_x$.  That's a property that we *want* to be true, if the topology is to play a role!

One more argument.  Look at the central limit theorem, one of the most important and influential theorems in probability theory and arguably in all of mathematics. Weak convergence gives us a mode of convergence for which the central limit theorem holds.  Your version with Borel indicators does not.  Not even for the very elementary version in which all the $\xi_n$ are Bernoulli; in that case the law of every $S_n/\sqrt{n}$ gives measure $1$ to the countable set $\{ n/\sqrt{m} : n,m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, to which the normal distribution assigns measure 0.

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

A notion of convergence is basically a way to discuss what it means to approximate a point (here, the point is actually a distribution) well by a sequence.

A typical probabilistic way to approximate a probability distribution is by random sampling. Let $\mu$ be a probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ and $x_1,x_2,\ldots,$ be independently distributed random variables that all have distribution $\mu$. One can show that the random sequence $\langle \mu_n\rangle$ with $\mu_n$ given by
$$\mu_n(A)=1/n~\#\big\{i:x_i\in A, i=1,\ldots,n\big\}$$
converges weakly to $\mu$. But every $\mu_n$ is discrete. In particular, there will always exist a countable set $C$ (depending on the realization) such that $\mu_n(C)=1$ for all $n$. If $\mu$ is continuous, we must have $\mu(C)=0\neq 1=\lim_n\mu_n(C)$. So such approximations would not work, a probability distribution cannot be approximated by sample realizations.

Answer (score 0):

I think a clear answer is in Chapter 9 of "Measure Theory and Probability Theory" of Krishna B. Athreya Soumendra N. Lahiri.

The authors suggest that the rationale behind the definition of weak convergence is to provide an analogy to the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem for probability measures. Indeed, it can be proven that under certain conditions, a set of probability measures always admits a subsequence that converges in terms of weak convergence.

In definition 9.2.1 they define weak converge on $\mathbb{R}$ only for set of the form $(a, b]$ with $a,b \in D$ for a $D$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$. As this set generates the sigma algebra it should be similar to your intuition on indicator functions.

In Theorem 9.2.2, they prove that this definition is equivalent to the one you stated in terms of continuous functions.

Comment: Weak convergence is equivalent to the condition that the cdfs $F_{\mu_n}$ converge pointwise to the cdf $F_\mu$ at every point of continuity of $F_\mu$ (and the set of points of discontinuity of $F_\mu$ is countable).